# How do i split a string in a list in python?

Tags: python

The list is:

```
key =['!"c5Ha:m']
```

how do i split it into

```
      ['!','"','c','H','a',':','m']
```

in order to  convert it into ASCII code.

Answer (score 2):

Call `list` on the item in the list:

```
>>> list(key[0])
['!','"','c','H','a',':','m']
```